# Volume of Sphere in Higher Dimension

Tags: integration, geometry, numerical-methods, python

Considering Gaussian shape  we can find the  volume of n dimensional volume of a sphere. My intention is to find the  volume using Monte Carlo method.

Using the gaussian integral I have found the formula

$$V_n = \frac{\pi^{(n/2)}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}$$

I know I have to define the random  function  to evaluate  the integral but I'm not sure how to do it. Any explicit explanation would be a huge help.

I would be grateful if anyone can  give a python code  for  finding  volume, so i can check more intuitively.

Comment: Not really about the question, but shouldn't it be called something other than volume? I think mass is the proper word, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Mass and volume are essentially the same thing, assuming a constant density $\rho$. Define your units so $\rho = 1$ and you are done.

Comment: Can you write a little bit details Nick? I want to write down python code for  hypersphere  and therefore I really need  clear understanding about the  random distribution  of the  volume equation.

Comment: @JacobClaassen Volume sounds good to me. "Hypervolume" sounds pretentious, and "mass" is a physicist's word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This started out as a comment but it was too long, so I made it an answer, although it's more a roadmap than anything else.]

You should use your system library's random function: defining your own is fraught with peril (bear in mind that the system routine may have problems as well - consult the "Numerical Recipes" book for some details, but be aware that the subject is deep).

You need it to return uniformly distributed random numbers between $-1.0$ and $1.0$. Each n-tuple of random numbers corresponds to a point inside the n-dimensional hypercube of volume $2^n$. The ratio of those points inside the n-dimensional ball to the total number of points will then be roughly the same as the ratio of the volume of the ball to that of the cube.  You figure out whether the point is inside the ball by calculating its Euclidean distance from the origin and seeing whether it's less than or equal to the radius (which is 1). Do that for as many points as you think you'll need to get a reasonable estimate of the volume. There is no good way to guess that: in most instances, you'll have to do it for some number of points and then repeat with twice as many (or ten times as many or $2^n$ times as many) points and seeing whether the estimate seems to converge. This is a naive approach: there are probably better approaches but for an initial acquaintance with Monte Carlo, it's probably good enough.

Lather, rinse, repeat for each $n$ of interest.

Also bear in mind that Monte Carlo is *not fast*: in fact, it's the method of last resort when you don't know of a better way. And the higher the dimension, the more darts you'll have to throw to get a reasonable estimate, so it gets slower as $n$ gets bigger.

Comment: "the more darts you have to throw" - Understatement of the century.

Comment: is there any source of python code  you can give me, so i can follow and  try to understand it? I have found some C and matlab online  but I want to do it  on python.

Comment: @NumericalPerson Do you know how to code in Python? If you do, here is a simple warm-up exercise. We are going to define a unit square - to do this, we need to pull a random set of 2-tuples, pairs of values of the form $(x,y)$. Since this is a unit square (centered at origin), both $x$ and $y$ can come from the interval $[-1/2,1/2]$. Generate $n$ 2-tuples this way. Now we can define a unit disk with the equation $x^2+y^2 \le 1$. We can check each pair $(x,y)$ and see if it satisfies this equation. Once we know which satisfy the equation, we just divide the number of point that do by the...

Comment: No, but you should be able to write a more-or-less direct transcription of the description above in an hour or so (assuming you have some experience with python). I'm sure you can google it and find something, but I think it's better if you write the program yourself.

Comment: ...total number of points. This gives us a proportion (a real number between $0$ and $1$) which is asymptotically equivalent to the area of the circle divided by the area of the square. If we define the area of the square to simply be $1$, then estimating the area of the circle is trivial. Now do the same thing with the unit cube and use $3$-tuples instead. Then the $4$-cube and $4$-tuples. Then the $n$-cube and $n$-tuples

Comment: Note however, that this is a circle of radius $1/2$. I suggested the range $[-1.0, 1.0]$ so that the radius is $1$. But it does mean that you have to divide by the volume of the cube (the area of the square in @BrevanEllefsen's example would then be 4).

Comment: @Nick Wow. I always forget how slow Monte Carlo is. $100000$ data points and I could barely recover the constant $\pi$ to the digits $3.14$

Comment: +1. Pretty nice. I read your answer after I wrote my $\texttt{javascript}$  code.

Comment: I +1'd your answer too :) It was nice to have the javascript code: it's far enough from python so that the translation exercise (and hopefully the prose in my answer) should prove useful to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `javascript` example ( you can translate to Phyton ). I enclose the sphere in a cube of side $2$. $\vec{0}$ is the common origin of the cube and the sphere.

It runs in a terminal with `node` as

$\texttt{node nSphere0.js}$

```
"use strict"; // nSphere0.js. Felix Marin. 02-april-17.
/*
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261623/volume-of-sphere-in-higher-dimension/2261779#2261779
*/

function nSphereVolume(dim,iter)
{
 var      i = 0;
 var      j = null;
 var      r = null;
 var total0 = null;
 var total1 = 0;

 while (i < iter) {
       total0 = 0;
       for ( j = 0 ; j < dim ; ++j ) {
           r = 2.0*Math.random() - 1.0;
           total0 += r*r;
       }

       if (total0 < 1.0) ++total1;
       ++i;
 }

 return Math.pow(2.0,dim)*(total1/iter);
}

console.log("Volume = " + nSphereVolume(3,10000)/(4.0*Math.PI/3.0));
```

> A 'typical run' yields

$\texttt{1.0061138882497258}$

The example is for a $3$D-sphere where I already divided by
$\displaystyle{4\pi \over 3}$. The exact result must be $\displaystyle{\color{#f00}{1}}$.